# While loop-increment the counter twice

Tags: python

I would like to know why in the code below one needs to increment the counter two times, the first time inside the if statement and a second time outside. In case the else part is omitted, one gets the expected result though. In case the outer counter is omitted, the loop is not ending. I want thus to understand why the inner counter is not sufficient to produce what we expect. Thanks.

```
w2 = 0
while w2 <= 17:
   if w2 % 2 == 0:
      print(w2)
   elif w2 == 9:
      break
   else:
      w2 +=1
      continue
   w2 += 1
```

Comment: The branch that contains one of the increments also has a `continue`, so it won't hit the second increment during that iteration.  It would be equivalent to move the second increment immediately after the `print`, or to remove the `else` branch in its entirety.

Comment: If you hit the `else`, then the outer increment will be skipped (because you `continue`). If you *don't* hit the `else`, well, then the `else` increment won't execute. So yeah, if you want it to increment in both cases, with this code, you need it in both branches. Or you can just omit the entire `else`.

Comment: Though this entire increment thing should be handled with `for w in range(18):`, then omit any manual incrementation.

Answer (score 0):

Odd numbers below 9 will increase `w2` twice, since they fall in the `else` branch. Without the `else` you always increase once until you reach 9, so you will print all even numbers below 9. Without the outer increase you will remain stuck on 0 because you won't increase `w2` anymore.
This code will print 0 and nothing else.

Also, I assume `w=0` meant `w2=0`

Answer (score 0):

The inner counter should be sufficient if you remove the elif. No need to break if w2 == 9. It is incrementing by 2 so it will skip the 9

```
w2 = 0
while w2 <= 17:
   if w2 % 2 == 0:
     print(w2)
   else:
     w2 +=1
    continue
w2 += 1
```